# Displaying privately hosted text file contents in Android app

Tags: android, json, parsing, hosting

I am relatively new to Android development, so I am a bit confused with the terminology and best practices for what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Title 1 = Bob
Description 1 = (paragraph)

Title 2 = Kevin
Description 2 = (paragraph)

...
```

I would like to host this file publicly on GitHub or Google Drive, and call it from an Android application with some XML formatting. The reason I want the information online is because updating would be much easier. I have played around with JSON before while learning from an open-source wallpaper app, but I was wondering if this would be the best route here, or if I should look into "parsing" or something else altogether.

Could you point me in the right direction with articles to read? Thank you!